# How do I create a custom JsonStringEnumConverter which converts strings to enums through switch statements?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, system.text.json

I watched this interesting video: [C#'s Enum performance trap your code is suffering from](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoE5Y6Xkm6w) and I wanted to implement something similair.

Basically, instead of using the following slow example:

```
public FolderTypeEnum FolderType
{
     get => Enum.TryParse(Type, out FolderTypeEnum status) ? status : FolderTypeEnum.None;
     set => Type = value.ToString();
}
```

You create an extension method which maps the string to the enum:

```
public static FolderTypeEnum ToFolderType(this string value)
{
    return value switch
    {
        "None" => FolderTypeEnum.None,
        "DownloadFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.DownloadFolder,
        "MovieFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.MovieFolder,
        "TvShowFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.TvShowFolder,
        "MusicFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.MusicFolder,
        "PhotosFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.PhotosFolder,
        "OtherVideosFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.OtherVideosFolder,
        "GamesVideosFolder" => FolderTypeEnum.GamesVideosFolder,
        "Unknown" => FolderTypeEnum.Unknown,
        _ => DefaultException(),
    };

    FolderType DefaultException()
    {
        Log.Error($"Failed to convert string \"{value}\" to type {nameof(FolderTypeEnum)}");
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value, null);
    }
}

public static string ToFolderTypeString(this FolderType value)
{
    return value switch
    {
        FolderType.None => "None",
        FolderType.DownloadFolder => "DownloadFolder",
        FolderType.MovieFolder => "MovieFolder",
        FolderType.TvShowFolder => "TvShowFolder",
        FolderType.MusicFolder => "MusicFolder",
        FolderType.PhotosFolder => "PhotosFolder",
        FolderType.OtherVideosFolder => "OtherVideosFolder",
        FolderType.GamesVideosFolder => "GamesVideosFolder",
        FolderType.Unknown => "Unknown",
        _ => DefaultException(),
    };

    string DefaultException()
    {
        Log.Error($"Failed to convert \"{value}\" to string of type {nameof(FolderType)}");
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(value), value, null);
    }
}
```

This works nicely, my next step was integrating this in all API calls and I figured I could create an [JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) and replace the fully working [JsonStringEnumConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-5.0)

```
public class FolderTypeConverter: JsonConverter<FolderTypeEnum>
{
    public override FolderTypeEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        return reader.GetString().ToFolderType();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, FolderTypeEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToFolderTypeString());
    }
}
```

Which is then registered in the `Startup.cs` class:

```
services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(
        options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new FolderTypeConverter());
        });
```

Unfortunately, this converter does not get called when serialization needs to happen? Anyone see what I did wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: The way I often do high-performance enum parsing is to use a dictionary `Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)).Zip((T[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)), (n, v) => (n, v)).ToDictionary(nv => nv.n, nv => nv.v)` this leaves you with a dictionary of enum names and enum values (you can do the same in reverse) and `T` is generic so you can use it with any enum

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set `JsonConverter` attribute on the class, that needs it, in your case the `FolderTypeEnum` class, like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(FolderTypeConverter))]
public class FolderTypeEnum
{
}
```

Then it should work automatically.